# plot number of occurrences (conditional selection) from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a DataFrame with three columns. 1) One of them is containing timestamps, 2) the second is containing the level of the errors (Level 1, Level 2 and Level 3) and the third the category of the errors (Category 1, Category 2 and Category 3)

I would like to know how many errors of a certain level and category have been performed in a certain day. For example, for every day I would like to count the number of the error occurrences of Level 1 of Category 1, and plot this data with date on X axis and number of occurrences on Y axes. I would appreciate if you could provide an answer by using pandas and matplotlib.

```
Time                    Level       Category
2000-12-29 00:10:00     Level 1     Category 1
2000-12-29 00:20:00     Level 2     Category 2
2000-12-29 00:30:00     Level 3     Category 3
2000-12-29 00:40:00     Level 3     Category 3
2000-12-29 00:50:00     Level 3     Category 3
...
2000-12-31 00:10:00     Level 3     Category 3
2000-12-31 00:20:00     Level 2     Category 2
2000-12-31 00:30:00     Level 1     Category 1
```

data.time, data.level and data.category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you start off with something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Time': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Level': [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
    'Category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a']})
```

First add a dummy column:

```
df['dummy'] = 1
```

Now just select the level and category, groupby the time, add the dummy per the group, and plot:

```
df[(df.Category == 'a') & (df.Level == 2)][['Time', 'dummy']].dummy.groupby([df.Time]).sum().plot();
```

[image: Resulting plot]